# keyboard issues in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am unable to click the submit button which placed at the bottom of the page. The keyboard just won't disappear and blocking the submit button.
i had implemented the coding i found here, but it is not working.

```
  InputMethodManager inputMgr =    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    Amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMSAmount);
    Amount.clearFocus();
    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Amount.getWindowToken(),  InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

P/S: the edit text field is number type, and entire page only having one edit text field